# Three.js Show single vertex as ie. a dot

Tags: three.js, vertices

Is it any way possible to show vertices of a mesh as ie. colored dots?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Done. Still new to SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to answer part A here, I recommend splitting your question up into two questions makes the site more useful for when other people are searching for the same solutions.

A [Mesh](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Mesh) has a [Geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) and a [Geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) has an array of [Vertices](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3).

From [Mesh](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Mesh) documentation.

> **Properties**
>
> .geometry
>
> An instance of Geometry, defining the object's structure.

From [Geometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) documentation.

> **Properties**
>
> .vertices
>
> Array of vertices. The array of vertices holds every position of
>   points in the model. To signal an update in this array,
>   Geometry.verticesNeedUpdate needs to be set to true.

To draw the vertices you can create a billboard particle at each one. [Below is a slight altered version of the billboard particle example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_particles_billboards.html).

```
//editGeometry = the geometry who's vertices we want to show

geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

sprite = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/sprites/disc.png" );

for ( i = 0; i < editGeometry.vertices.length; i ++ ) {

    geometry.vertices.push(editGeometry.vertices[i]);

}

material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: 35, sizeAttenuation: false, map: sprite, transparent: true } );
material.color.setHSL( 1.0, 0.3, 0.7 );

particles = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );
particles.sortParticles = true;
scene.add( particles );
```

Comment: I see. It makes sense.
Maybe this would also solve the second problem (I will post about this in a seperate question then).
Three.js would be able to register i I clicked on this billboard and "dragged" it somewhere on the screen.